# Run Python file/script in React Native

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, react-native

Is there a way to run a Python script or file in a React Native app?

I've tried successfully to run a Python script in a node.js file with the following methods, but these methods break when I try them with React native:

I followed this tutorial to run Python in Node.js **using child_process**. This code worked in a standalone Node.js file, but when run with the React Native app I got an error saying the child_process module couldn't be resolved even after I imported it.

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-python-script-node-js-using-child-process-spawn-method/

I also tried this tutorial to run Python scripts in Node.js **using the npm module python-shell**. Again, this code works in a standalone Node.js file, but when run with the React Native app, this error came up: "undefined Unable to resolve module 'events' from 'node_modules\python-shell\index.js"

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell

Can you please advise me on how I could run a Python script in React Native or how I could resolve the above errors? Thank you!

Comment: React native is not node js, why would you expect that to work? React native compiles to native code. Its even in the name.